# What are the ??? gems for?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Every now and then, instead of getting a weapon gem over SpotPass, Palutena sends over a ??? gem instead. They can't be converted into weapons, they can't be fused, and selling them provides a measly 5 hearts.

If I had to guess, these gems represent locked weapons (e.g. Zodiac weapons) and will reveal their "true forms" once said weapons are unlocked. Is this it, or something else entirely?

Comment: You May Be Right It May Be A Locked Weapon  [!Source!](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/50545/t1734487-gem/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem is ??? because you have to unlock it in a Treasure Hunt, or find the equivalent Zodiac weapon.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that you unlock the ??? Gem if you continue playing the game, it eventually will become a weapon, or you haven't found it in the treasure hunt.